# SQLite3 C++, need a workaround for a sqlite3_stepback

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, visual-studio-2022

I'm currently programming a .dll in C++ using the functionalities from the sqlite3.c file which can be found in the official [SQLite page](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)

The sqlite3.c contains various functions to do basic stuff with sqlite3 like connect to a DB, open a recordset, execute SQL statements, etc..

One of the functions used to navigate to the next returned record in a recordset is sqlite3_step. Unfortunately, there is not a sqlite_stepback or something similar.

In my case, I need to do a step and then do a stepback in a function to determine the size of the data that will be returned, so that the application using the .dll creates a buffer of the correct size to allocate all the data that will be returned.

I need help with any of these two possible workarounds:

- Generate a sort of stepback function, issue being that I don't know the inner workings of sqlite3.c.
- The recordsets are stored in what seems to be a struct defined as sqlite3_stmt. For my particular issue I could copy the full sqlite3_stmt to another variable, do a step in the copied sqlite3_stmt, and then destroy it, leaving intact the original recordset in its current position. I haven't managed to find a way to properly copy a sqlite3_stmt.

I think the best option if possible, would be the second one.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/reset.html, but any scheme using this count then read is inefficient, you'll scan the result set twice whatever you do. Appending rows to a vector if you need to cache everything will only scan once.

Comment: @Mat the reset function resets the prepared statement object. If I'm in the 4th record of the returned recordset, it will take me back to the 1st one and that is not what I want to do. If for example I'm in the 4th record of my recordset, I want to advance to the 5th one to check what data will come next, and then go back to the 4th record again.

Comment: That sounds very strange Can't you use a window function instead (e.g. lag/lead)?

Comment: SQLite compiles SQL queries into basic instructions, typically with a loop for a `SELECT`, which are then interpreted. In this situation, what you basically ask for is to revert execute those instructions. Like in a CPU, this isn't possible.

Comment: @prapin It seems to be possible. For example, in MSAccess you have the following: [MSAccess move first, last, next and previous](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/movefirst-movelast-movenext-and-moveprevious-methods-example-vb)

As you can see, there is a MovePrevious method with the recordset. That is something similar of what I would like to achieve in SQLIte3 in C++.

This is not just something of MSAccess, you can do this in mySQL for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to do a step and then do a stepback in a function to determine the size of the data that will be returned

No, you don't.  If you did, someone else would have needed it before you, and the function would exist.  Therefore we know some other way is possible, and probably better.

Just reorganize how you're accepting requests from the caller versus how you're interacting with SQLite.  Maybe, in some sense, you have to be "one step ahead" of the application to provide it with the information it requires.

When sqlite3_step returns, you can call any number of functions to determine the values in the row and their sizes. You have what you need. There's no need at that juncture to go back to the previous row.

In case you doubt me, I worked on [FreeTDS](https://www.freetds.org) for many years.   The TDS protocol is a stream from the DBMS.  There's no "going back".  FreeTDS offers three APIs, all of which do have some kind of client-side cursor to let the application scroll back to previously provided rows.  But that functionality takes place entirely within the client library, with no server interaction.

I implemented some of that, but never used it in any of my applications.  The fastest way through the data is forward, once.

Comment: Hello, thanks for you response!
My case is a very special scenario.

I'm using a game development software known as Game Maker Studio 2. Game Maker Studio 2 has the ability to create buffers and it is my only way of returning multiple values from a .DLL.
A .DLL can't resize a GMS buffer, a buffer created by GMS can only be resized by GMS itself.
This is why, I need to ask the .DLL what is the size I will need to store the information of the next record.
I have to do this in three steps: First call the DLL to know the size, resize my buffer in GMS, then let the DLL populate the buffer.

Comment: It's not special at all, Alex.  It's quite common for an API to provide a way for the caller to interrogate some kind of handle about its size, let it allocate a buffer, and then make the call. In your case, you need 2 calls, say "next_row_info" and "next_row_data".  The "info" function calls sqlite3_next, computes the size(s), and returns that to the caller.  The "data" function returns the data, but does not step.  Something like that should do the trick.

Comment: I just tryed your solution of dividing it in 2 calls. It works that way and I will stick with this method.
I think my main problem was that I just wanted to have all in one unique call, but it seems failry more simple to do it in 2 different calls.
Thank you!